# How Create Different action bar in fragments, with navGraphHost. ANDROID

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-actionbar

I'm new in android, So basically what I want to achieve is to have appBottomBar with navGraphHost. I have one activity_main where is hosted NavGraph and have 3 fragments. I implemented it and its works fine. Know the problem is that on every fragment toolbar is same, I have to make different toolbars according fragment  on first fragment should be button in toolbar, on second fragment should be search box and etc. I tried to remove action bar from theme.xml  and  add toolbar on each  fragment, but it works kinda weird, one problem I had was that, in one fragment I have button and when you click on it it navigate on 4th fragment and the backstack button was removed from toolbar and there was also other bugs, I also tried on internet other solutions but nothing was useful, If someone has experience how to achieve my goal please give advice, thanks in advance.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        return navController.navigateUp()

    }

}
```

**activity_main XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_notifications_to_pageOne2"
            app:destination="@id/pageOne2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pageOne2"
        android:name="com.example.PageOne"
        android:label="fragment_page_one"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_page_one" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_pageOne2_to_pageTwo2"
            app:destination="@id/pageTwo2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pageTwo2"
        android:name="com.example.pageTwo"
        android:label="fragment_page_two"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_page_two" />
</navigation>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar)? Every fragment can add buttons/a search bar to your action bar.

Comment: @ianhanniballake first of all thanks for your response, I read it now but couldn't figure how to change or add button on action bar  in specific fragment,   in my app action bar is hosted by theme